# Subscripts going out of range in an array

Tags: c, loops

Here the subscripts of the array are out of range.

```
 int a[10], i;
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
a[i] = 0;
printf("India");
```

The output is an infinte loop and printf statment doesnt get executed. here's what written in K N King:

When i reaches 10. the program stores 0 into a [10] . But a [10] doesn’t exist.
so 0 goes into memory immediately after a [9] . If the variable i happens to follow
a [9] in memory—as might be the case—then i will be reset to O. causing the
loop to start over.

Can anyone explain it ?

Comment: The array index is **zero** based, i.e. in your example, 0 to 9, and not 1 to 10.

Comment: why it is infinte loop

Comment: Because `i` is probably stored in the memory location just after the array `a` (i.e. where `a[10]` would be), so when `i` reaches 10, `a[i] = 0` resets `i` to zero.

Comment: @RidhimaSharma: There is no reason, just undefined behaviour due to the out-of-bounds access. Possibly, it overwrites `i`, setting it back to zero, as described in your quote; or it could do anything else.

Comment: @RidhimaSharma, accessing out of bounds memory is cause for defined behavior. You can't justify a particular undefined behavior using reason. The behavior you see could change if you change compilers or even compiler options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea that this will form an infinite loop is based on an assumption about how the variables will be laid out in memory. In particular, it assumes that because `i` is *defined* immediately after `a`, that it will also be allocated in memory immediately after `a`.

That's certainly not guaranteed, but it equally certainly could happen. If it does, then the write to `a[10]` may actually overwrite `i`. Since it's writing `0` into the nonexistent `a[10]`, doing so actually writes `0` into `i`. Then when the condition in the loop checks that `i <= 10`, that's true, so the loop continues -- and each time `i` gets to 10, it's immediately overwritten with 0 *before* the loop condition is evaluated, so the loop re-starts from the beginning.

As far as either the C or C++ standard cares, it's just undefined behavior--when the code writes past the end of the array *anything* can happen. It might do what somebody expects, or might might do something *entirely* different and unrelated that doesn't seem to make sense at all. The compiler is free to emit code that does pretty much anything in such a circumstance (or it could, for example, diagnose it as an error, and emit no code at all).

To give some idea of what conforming behavior *could* be: early versions of gcc had code to detect a specific case of implementation-defined behavior (pretty much like undefined behavior, except the implementation has to document what it does). In this case, the documented behavior was fairly complex. The compiler would attempt to do each of the following in order (and stop at the first one that succeeded):

1. run nethack (a game)
2. run rogue (another game)
3. start emacs, and have it execute a towers of hanoi simulation
4. print out "You are in a maze of twisty little passages, all alike".

I could be getting the order of those a bit wrong (this was a *long* time ago), but you get the idea. The result had *nothing* to do with anything a reasonable person would be likely to expect.

Comment: +1 for various UB especially "You are in a maze of twisty little passages, all alike".   Hmmm, A hollow voice says "Plugh".